# Set hostname without root, and without CAP_SYS_ADMIN

Tags: linux, permissions, hostname, capabilities, setcap

I have an application that I want to be able to change the hostname in Linux.  Currently doing so by running the hostname command.  I don't want to set CAP_SYS_ADMIN either.  I also don't want to edit /etc/hostname and reboot.

Is there a capability that only just allows changing the hostname?  If not what are my options?

Comment: an entry in /etc/sudoers ?

Comment: This worked for me.  visudo.  "username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/hostname".  Why not put that in an answer so I can award you points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the hostname in linux is done via the sethostname(2) syscall. And /bin/hostname is a bare wrapper around this syscall (and a few related syscalls). /etc/hostname is supposed to be read during the boot process by some script, who subsequently runs /bin/hostname to complish its job.

CAP_SYS_ADMIN is one of linux capabilities(7), allows a thread to perform *various* system administration operations, which include *sethostname*. I'm not aware of a smaller ganularity within the capabilities framework.

However there are other options. We can grant some user ability to run some command *as* another user, by sudo(8), in a customisable manner. This example sudoers(5) configuration will allow user alice to run /bin/hostname as root.

```
alice ALL=(root:ALL) /bin/hostname
```

As [described in this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/357467/what-do-the-alls-in-the-line-admin-all-all-all-in-ubuntus-etc-sudoers), the first "ALL" can be replaced by the hosts where the command is run on, not of use unless in a cooperative environment. "root" can be replaced by "ALL" to allow alice to run as *any* user. Second "ALL" can be replaced by the groups.

The last field is commands alice is allowed to run. As /bin/hostname has limited usage, I guess it is fine. Otherwise we may have it followed by an argument, thus alice cannot run the command without this argument, to restrain the power.

Comment: Antonius Bloch, I feel honoured you would like my comment. While I do love a little more reputation myself, I will also be happy if you to expand my comment and write your own answer.